# no functionality in ie6

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Hi,

Appreciate I'm in an extreme minority using ie6 (at work, where I have no choice to upgrade or use alternatives) but with the other stackexchange sites I use (stackoverflow and webmasters) I can reply to questions, add comments and vote. In programmers I don't seem to be able to do any of these.

I'm not going to lose sleep if this doesn't get fixed, I understamnd the pain ie6 causes - just seems odd that some stack exchange sites are ie6 functional, whilst this one isn't.

Comment: Why can't you upgrade?  IE6 is not only extremely outdated, but unsecure.  You should talk to your management about getting that problem fixed :)

Comment: We have: http://www.hmg.gov.uk/epetition-responses/petition-view.aspx?epref=ie6upgrade

Answer (score 8):

I agree, it is odd since they are all using the same engine -- therefore it has to be the css of this particular site.

Can you try disabling stylesheets?

We don't want to spend any additional engineering resources on ie6 at this point.

Answer (score 5):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign): IE6 is not supported at all, and even IE7 is minimally supported. Check Meta Stack Overflow for [a list of browsers that are currently supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported/71208#71208). Things might work in IE6 on some sites, but working functionality is purely coincidental.

Comment: That's cool, thanks for replying. Just a small point, in the post you link to Jeff states "The site will work in IE6 but may not look entirely correct." It seems this is not the case.